# jQuery toggle not toggling correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Examplation**

In my understanding you can just check if the variable has a truth value or not. That means
if( value ) {
}

will evaluate to true if value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

In my javascript I have;

```
$("#AccountDetails_Name").text(data.Name);
$("#AccountDetails").toggle(data.Name);
```

and this html;

```
<div id="AccountDetails" class="alert alert-warning" style="display:none;">
    <strong>Name:</strong> <span id="AccountDetails_Name">@Model.AccountName</span>
</div>
```

When I am debugging the javascript I breakpoint on the line that toggles the div's visibility and can see that data.Name equals "Mr Tom Hanson". However, the div "AccountDetails" is hidden from view.

**What is happening**
The div is not showing when data.Name is has a value

**What I want to happen**
The div to show on the form when data.Name has a valuwe

**What I did to solve it**
I changed this line

```
$("#AccountDetails").toggle(data.Name);
```

to

```
$("#AccountDetails").toggle(data.Name != null && data.Name != "");
```

However I am confused as to why the original did not work

Comment: `.toggle()` expects a boolean value as argument

Comment: @gurvinder372 can you add yours as an answer so I can mark it. That works great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***falsey*** is not exactly same as `false`.

`typeof false` is `boolean` while falsey could be `number` and `string` as well.

Simply try

```
$("#AccountDetails").toggle(Boolean(data.Name));
```

or

```
$("#AccountDetails").toggle(!!(data.Name));
```